# Does Go execute all the conditions in "if' if the first fails?

Tags: go, if-statement, execution

Imagine the following piece of code:

```golang
if someBool && funcReturningABool() {
    // code here...
}
```

where `someBool` is a boolean and `funcReturningABool` returns true or false.

If `someBool` is equal to false, will the `funcReturningABool` still be executed?

Comment: No, it won't be executed.

Answer (score 5):

As you can find in [the Golang documentation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Logical_operators):

> The right operand is evaluated conditionally

Answer (score 4):

it will not, and it is applicable not only to golang.

[image]